# texindy equivalence to makeindex settings

Tags: formatting, indexing, xindy

I'm currently using makeindex to generate an index and was advised by @egreg to use xindy instead to properly manage accents in French. However, I can't find how to reproduce my current settings:

```
\makeindex[title={Index th\'ematique},intoc,options=-r -s thematique.ist,columns=2]
\newcommand{\themeindex}[1]{\index{#1|transform}}
```

I then use `\themeindex` in my text.

`thematique.ist` contains:

```
% Dotfill style
headings_flag 1
heading_prefix "\\hfill\{\\dayheadfont\\large\\textbf- "
heading_suffix " -\}\\hfill\\nopagebreak\\vspace\{0.5\\baselineskip\}"
delim_0 "\\dotfill "
delim_1 "\\dotfill "
delim_2 "\\dotfill "
item_0 "\n \\item\\raggedright "
item_1 "\n \\subitem\\raggedleft "
```

How can I achieve the same with xindy?

Comment: This requires going deeply in the manual of Xindy. If it existed. :(

Comment: Is xindy that old? And if it is old and good, why don't people use it more?

Comment: It's a rather old project, but it lacks documentation. And still has a few problems, unfortunately, in UTF-8 support.

Answer (score 6):

It was quite difficult to accomplish this task without a full MWE or a preview of index at hand. I tried that anyway and this is an example of an index with French words. I run these commands:

> lualatex mal-xindy-style.tex
> xindy -M texindy -C utf8 -L french -M mal-makeindex-style mal-xindy-style.idx
> lualatex mal-xindy-style.tex

If we change `\usepackage{luatextra}` to `inputenc` (for `pdflatex`) or to `fontspec` (for `xelatex`), this example will be displaying letters with diacritics in those formats.

```
%! lualatex mal-xindy-style.tex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{luatextra} % Use inputenc with pdflatex or fontspec with xelatex to achieve proper displaying of letters with diacritics.
\pagestyle{empty}\parindent=0pt
\usepackage[hyperindex=false, colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex %[title={Index th\'ematique}, intoc, options=-r -s thematique.ist,columns=2]
\newcommand{\themeindex}[1]{\index{#1|malindex}}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\font\dayheadfont=cmr10 %at 12pt
\def\myheadingstart{%\def\indexspace{}%\justify\hfil
  \centering\begingroup\dayheadfont\large\bfseries-- }
\def\myheadingend{ --\endgroup\nopagebreak\vspace{0.5\baselineskip}\par\raggedright}
\def\myown#1{\textit{#1}}
\def\mallettergroup#1{\myheadingstart#1\myheadingend}
\def\malindex#1{\myown{\hyperpage{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\ifx\relax
% An original file for makeindex...
\begin{filecontents*}{thematique.ist} 
% Dotfill style
headings_flag 1
heading_prefix "\\myheadingstart "
heading_suffix " \\myheadingend "
delim_0 "\\dotfill "
delim_1 "\\dotfill "
delim_2 "\\dotfill "
item_0 "\n \\item\\raggedright "
item_1 "\n \\subitem\\raggedleft "
\end{filecontents*}
\fi

% A style file for xindy...
\begin{filecontents*}{mal-makeindex-style.xdy}
(markup-index :open  "\begin{theindex}~n"
    :close "~n~n\end{theindex}~n"
    :tree) 

(markup-letter-group :open-head "~n\mallettergroup{" :close-head "}%")
(markup-letter-group-list :sep "~n~n\indexspace~n")

(markup-indexentry :open "~n\item " :close "" :depth 0)
(markup-indexentry :open "~n  \subitem " :close "" :depth 1)
(markup-indexentry :open "~n    \subsubitem " :close "" :depth 2)
(markup-locclass-list :open "\dotfill " :sep ", " :close "")
(markup-locref-list   :sep ", ")

(define-attributes (("malindex")) )
(markup-locref :attr "malindex" :open "\malindex{" :close "}")
(markup-locref :attr "hyperpage" :open "\hyperpage{" :close "}")
(markup-locref :attr "default" :open "\hyperpage{" :close "}")
\end{filecontents*}

\index{premier niveau}
\index{niveau!1@premier}
\index{niveau!2@deuxième}
\index{niveau!1@premier!1@premier}
\index{niveau!1@premier!2@deuxième}
\themeindex{niveau!2@deuxième!1@premier}
\themeindex{niveau!2@deuxième!2@deuxième}
\index{étrangères}
\index{Ça va}
\index{À quelle}
\themeindex{éteindre}
\themeindex{surhomme}
\themeindex{œil}

\begingroup
% I wish not to have page number in index.
\def\indexname{Index thématique}%
\def\thispagestyle#1{}%
\printindex
\endgroup
My first paragraph\ldots
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Comment: I believe you when you say this took some figuring! I'm even linking and commenting in my source code (not that it wouldn't be obvious this snippet was above my head). The only adjustment and possible contribution was that since I'm using imakeidx and texindy, I cleaned up the things to remember at compile time by moving the language arguments into the xdy file itself (in my case `(require "lang/turkish/utf8-lang.xdy")` and used `makeindex[options=-M filename.xdy]`. Compiling is then simplified to just running lualatex. Thanks for working out this snippet!

Comment: @Caleb It's good to hear it's working for you after some adjustments!

Comment: Could something have changed over the last few years? When I run the second command I get the error message: `xindy: input file mal-xindy-style.idx does not exist at /usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64-linux/xindy line 547.` under TeXLive'20

Comment: @TeXApprentice: It works fine for me. Just had to replace `-C UTF8` by `-C urtf8`. Did you name the tex file as `mal-xindy-style.tex`?

Comment: @SergeiGolovan `urtf8` ??? What is that?

Comment: It's a typo. utf8.

Comment: @Malipivo, the command should use lowercase `-C utf8`. Would you edit your answer?