# Change sorting of authors in the index generated by Biblatex

Tags: biblatex, indexing, strings

I am looking for a way to change the way in which author (or editor) names are sorted in Biblatex-generated indexes.

In French, we use accented letters such as `é` or `è`, which should be sorted with the main letter, in this case `e`. Whenever a name contains such an accented letter, it gets sorted out of order, so we need to index entries using: `no accents@with accents`. I understand how to get Biblatex to use an `@` in the index, but not how to feed it the proper string.

How can I make sure that Biblatex either:

- converts such special characters to their equivalent basic latin letter before printing the name into the index (with Biber or any string manipulation package)
- uses a special name field such as `indexauthor`, which would contain a list of names using only basic latin characters
- tweak the index so that it properly sorts all special characters without having to use `@` (my base class is using memoir, so `makeidx` is the preferred engine)
- or anything else that works

The solution from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/282578/10119) works partially, as shown in the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[indexing=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{testcite,
  author = {Éliot, William and Doé, John},
  title = {Test Title},
  year = {2018},
  usera = {Eliot, William and Doe, John}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\renewbibmacro*{citeindex}{%
    {\indexnames{labelname}}{}}

\renewbibmacro*{index:name}[5]{%
  \usebibmacro{index:entry}{#1}
    {\iffieldundef{usera}{}{\thefield{usera}\actualoperator}\mkbibindexname{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}}}

\makeindex

\begin{document}

\printindex

\cite{testcite}

\end{document}
```

The first name gets indexed properly, as an `E` letter, but the second name also gets indexed as such, because we are using a literal field instead of a name field for the indexauthor name (in this case, `usera`).

Would it be possible to use a name field instead and make sure both names get indexed properly? I realise that this may be impossible due to the way in which fields work.

In that event, how could I convert the special characters on the fly? Or tweak the indexing process itself so that it sorts accented letters properly?

Comment: Now I don't have much experience with indices, but maybe you are better off using an index tool that can deal with UTF-8. `xindy` springs to mind, maybe `xindy` can sort your entries properly without manual intervention.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22785/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/131334/35864

Comment: @moewe Thanks a lot. I have to look into `xindy` more in depth… It seems to need some configuration before it prints things in the right order.

Comment: Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/118724/35864 can also help. The code of the question in  https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/175511/35864 might also be interesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need an index tool that can handle UTF8 correctly, then there is no need at all to manipulate the sorting manually. This is not really a `biblatex` problem, its an issue of the indexing tool.

You can use `xindy` together with `imakeidx`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[indexing=true,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage[xindy, noautomatic]{imakeidx}
\def\xindylangopt{-M texindy -L french -C utf8}
\makeindex[options=\xindylangopt]

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{testcite,
  author = {Éliot, William and Doé, John},
  title = {Test Title},
  year = {2018},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\printindex

\index{hallo}
\cite{testcite}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

compiled with

```
pdflatex document
biber document
pdflatex document
texindy -M texindy -L french -C utf8 document.idx
pdflatex document
pdflatex document
```

gives

[image]